# How can I make a trailing slash optional on a Django Rest Framework SimpleRouter

Tags: django, trailing-slash, django-rest-framework

The [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) say you can set `trailing_slash=False` but how can you allow both endpoints to work, with or without a trailing slash?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can override the [`__init__` method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e215db2/rest_framework/routers.py#L126) of the SimpleRouter class:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter


class OptionalSlashRouter(SimpleRouter):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.trailing_slash = '/?'
```

The `?` character will make the slash optional for all available routes.

Comment: Funny I was  thinking about this today. But I'm making use of url Router. Will try that and see what happens. +1

Comment: I use `DefaultRouter` and had to do this: `class OptionalSlashRouter(DefaultRouter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DefaultRouter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.trailing_slash = '/?'
`

Comment: You can pass `/?` [to](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.1/rest_framework/routers.py#L168) the [constructor](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter).

Comment: The __init__ method [overrides `trailing_slash` to always be `/`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/453196e9c3a581bac3bf68eb8c9cdd7d28d2dcd6/rest_framework/routers.py#L169) when truthy.

Comment: Put the super init method call before `self.trailing_slash = '/?'`.

Comment: Getting - `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^?$" is not a valid regular expression: nothing to repeat at position 1`. For this solution.

Answer (score 36):

You can also override this setting by passing a `trailing_slash` argument to the `SimpleRouter` constructor as follows:

```py
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

Comment: Then the URL with a trailing slash doesn't work though

Comment: That's the point, but in such case you will probably have to configure to support both at the http server level. Example: Apache has the mod_rewrite module and you can do a simple redirect to urls without trailing slash

Comment: If I have `trailing_slash=False`, and I write the URLs to register with a slash at the end, and have APPEND_SLASH not set to False, then both the URLs with and without the trailing slash work fine, as the URL without a trailing slash redirects to the one with a trailing slash.

Comment: The issue is, URLs for subpages from DRF such as `my_model/1/` become `my_model//1`. So it seems better to keep the default of `trailing_slash=True`, register the URL without a trailing slash, and have APPEND_SLASH=True.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using DRF's routers and viewsets, you can include `/?` in your prefix.

```
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import ClientViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r"clients/?", ClientViewSet)
```

Comment: I like this solution better, it gives you more control.

Answer (score 5):

I found the easiest way to do this is just to set up your URLs individually to handle the optional trailing slash, e.g.

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('api/end-point/?$', api.endPointView),
    ...
```

Not a DRY solution, but then it's only an extra two characters for each URL. And it doesn't involve overriding the router.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using `ExtendedSimpleRouter` in `rest_framework_extensions`, the accepted solution needs a small modification. The `self.trailling_slash` has to be after the `super().__init__()` like this.

```
from rest_framework_extensions.routers import ExtendedSimpleRouter

class OptionalSlashRouter(ExtendedSimpleRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExtendedSimpleRouter, self).__init__()
        self.trailing_slash = "/?"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `DefaultRouter` class, it's the same as Ryan Allen's answer:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


class OptionalSlashRouter(DefaultRouter):
    """Make all trailing slashes optional in the URLs used by the viewsets
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.trailing_slash = '/?'


router = OptionalSlashRouter()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For DefaultrRoter class, it can be done in a simpler way

```
from djoser import views

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```