# How to properly test Django API ListView with PyTest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I have an API ListView endpoint, which works properly when I shoot it with Postman, but returns empty queryset and status 404 in tests:

## test result:

```
web_1  | >       assert response.status_code == 200
web_1  | E       assert 404 == 200
```

I use pytest fixture to create my object:

## conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture
def event(system, new_conflict):
    return Event.objects.create(
        system=system,
        event_type='new_conflict',
        details=new_conflict
    )
```

Fixtures work fine in other (not API) tests, so I believe the problem might be in the way I'm testing my API. In pycharm debugger I can see that the view is executed, so it's not a url problem.

In postman, this endpoint properly returns a json with Event objects and status 200.

## test_api.py

```py
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from event_finder.models import Event
import pytest


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_list_events_all(event):
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.get(path='/api/events/', format='json')

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

## views.py

```py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

from event_finder.models import Event
from event_finder.serializers import EventSerializer


class ListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

Comment: Why not use django-rest-framework? Did you try and find any problem with that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, do you mean using DRF for tests? I have all other tests in pytest and it would be nice to stick with it. Plus I would really like to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: @luistm That's exactly how I'm running a test - using `from rest_framework.test import APIClient`, sending the request with `client.get()` and asserting the response, right? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are not storing the create transaction, try changing the deco to `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`

Comment: @hoefling thanks, but it still doesn't work. I'm considering giving up and making a standard factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently I'm an idiot and problem was totally different. My URL didn't work because of `/` in the end. Changed it to:

```
response = client.get(path='/api/events',
                          format='json')
```

and it works just fine. No idea why I didn't catch that before, I was running through the whole app with Pycharm debugger and the view was executed.

To be honest after reading [the docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html) I'm quite surprised my fixture works. According to the docs I should add `db` fixture to my fixture, but it works just fine without it.

Thanks for help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: When it comes to the trailing slack, maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163838/how-can-i-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-on-a-django-rest-framework-simplerouter

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example. But maybe you can make it work like this:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITransactionTestCase
from rest_framework.test import status

class TestThis(APITransactionTestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        data = {"key": "value"}
        response = self.client.post("/api/resource", data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not really. I know how to do that with TestCase and factories, but I'd rather avoid writing factories when I have fixtures ready from other tests. There must be a way to make them work. But thanks for trying.