# Make Django/DRF accept urls without trailing slash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to avoid `url` redirections to `url/` in Django/DjangoRestFramework? My point is that some frontend developers use `url` without trailing slashes and Django redirects such requests to `url/` which slows down the API.

Adding

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

to settings doesn't solve the problem as it returns `404` responses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a trailing slash optional on a Django Rest Framework SimpleRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163838/how-can-i-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-on-a-django-rest-framework-simplerouter)

Comment: There is also this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash.  These are both _trival_ google searches, and both point right back to stack overflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875343/make-django-drf-accept-urls-without-trailing-slash

Comment: @Andrew I explicitly wrote that `APPEND_SLASH=False` is not an option. It needs to be without a redirect and yes, I came across the first solution and I used it already, thanks.